# How to implement foreign key relationships with django-import-export

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-import-export, django-excel

I've made a django app in which I want to import data from .xlsx files to models with django-import-export module.

My models.py is:

```
class File(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Data(models.Model):
    file = models.ForeignKey(File,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    url = models.URLField()
```

I want that when I import .xlsx file its contents go into Data model and its File name into File model with foreign key relationship between them.

My admin.py file is:

```
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
from import_export import resources, fields
from import_export.widgets import ForeignKeyWidget
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import File, Data

admin.site.register(File)

class DataResource(resources.ModelResource):
    file = fields.Field(
        widget=ForeignKeyWidget(File, 'name'))

    class Meta:
        model = Data
        exclude = ('file',)


@admin.register(Data)
class DataAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    pass
```

I tried everything in the module's documentation. But I can't solve the issue I'm facing

Comment: I'd recommend creating a new view, with step1: Create File object, sstep2: Modify data and add file's id in each row of xlsx, or you can just use in in before import row, step:3 Import file using resources

Comment: What happens if you remove `file` from the `exclude` tuple?  This would stop that field from being processed https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html?highlight=exclude#customize-resource-options